# Is it possible to create a universal toast component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-directive

The basic key is that, if I have a toast component `toastComponent` with a selector as `<app-toast>`

Then in the root (app.component.html), I should only add the selector for the toast component once and from every other child component, I should only call the function to trigger toast with message and message type (success/error/warning).

So is it possible? I have been trying but not getting the results out.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you need to create one shared service to share between multiple component. Make sure you add ToastService in Providers array in module.

```
@Injectable()
export class ToastService {

  public duration =  3000;
  public horizontalPosition: 'left' | 'start' | 'end' | 'right' | 'center' | undefined = 'left';
  public verticalPosition: 'bottom' | 'top' | undefined = 'bottom';

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  public saveToast(
    message = 'Save Successful.',
    duration = this.duration,
    horizontalPosition = this.horizontalPosition,
    verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition
  ) {
    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ToastComponent, {
      data: message,
      duration,
      horizontalPosition,
      verticalPosition
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your toast component you have to add code to display snackbar. Make sure you add ToastComponent declaration and entrycomponents array in ur module:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'general-toast',
    template: `
    <div>
        <div>
            <span [innerHTML]="data> </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="dismissToast()">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
})

export class ToastComponent {

    constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
        public snackBar: MatSnackBar
    ) { }

    public dismissToast(): void {
        this.snackBar.dismiss();
    }

}
```

You are all set now. You just need to Inject ToastService in the constructor and call from your component.

Comment: I appreciate your response but I really don't want to use Ngbootstrap. Perhaps I want to write a custom component. Any leads for a custom component, I can add my current toastr component if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You even do not need to add a component selector to the root,You can look at this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

package like :sweetalert2 , izitoast and etc using similar method